# Autoload with Namespace - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MyClass" not found

Tags: php, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

Using spl_autoload_register() with a class that uses namespace, causes this error message: *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MyClass" not found...*

Before this error message, the autoloader does echo "...MyClass.php IS found".

Two files are used: "/index.php" (in the root directory) and "/classes/MyClass.php".

Index.php:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

define ('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__ . '/');
define ('CLASS_DIR', ROOT_DIR . 'classes/');

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $filepath = CLASS_DIR . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        require_once $filepath;
        echo('<br /><b>' . $filepath . '</b> IS found.<br />');
    } else {
        echo('<br /><b>' . $filepath . '</b> not found.<br />');
        exit;
    }
});

$myclass = new MyClass();
```

MyClass.php:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Classes

class MyClass
{
    // ...
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

According to https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/, a vendor name is required, so I am using "App" as a top-level namespace name, even though it is not a directory (because my website uses the root of the server).

I also tried adding "use App/classes/Myclass" to index.php before "$myclass = new MyClass()" but this causes even more problems, because the autoloader will look for the directory "/classes/App/Classes"...

With the namespace removed from the class, everything works fine, and I can use the functions of the class through $myclass. But I would like to start using namespaces... Any help would be really appreciated! <3

> **Conclusion**: Either the line "`$myclass = new App\Classes\MyClass();`"
> or "`use App\Classes\MyClass;`" should be used.
>
> So it is not possible to use the root of the server while also having a
> top-level namespace name ("App") with this autoload function. The
> function has to be expanded to allow for this possibility. And the "classes" directory will be renamed to "Classes". I will post my solution when it is ready!
>
> For more details, read the comments below the answer by @IMSoP (Thank
> you very much for your help!)

**Solution**:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

define ('ROOT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/');
define ('BASE_DIR', __DIR__ . '/');
define ('TOP_LEVEL_NAMESPACE_NAME', __NAMESPACE__ . '/');

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if (BASE_DIR == ROOT_DIR . TOP_LEVEL_NAMESPACE_NAME) {
        $filepath = ROOT_DIR . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';
    } else {
        $filepath = BASE_DIR . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';
        $filepath = str_replace(TOP_LEVEL_NAMESPACE_NAME, '', $filepath);
    }
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        require_once $filepath;
    } else {
        echo('Class <b>' . end(explode('\\', $class)) . '.php</b> was not found.');
        exit;
    }
});

use App\Classes\MyClass;

$myclass = new MyClass();
```

This solution works whether the application is in the directory with the same name as the top-level namespace name, or anywhere else!

Comment: With `namespace App\Classes\MyClass`, your *fully-qualified class name* is actually `App\Classes\MyClass\MyClass`, which is nonsense.

Comment: @deceze Thank you! I thought i did it right the first time, but then someone mentioned that i did not consistently use fully-qualified class names, and i figured that must be the place i had to change something (because it was the only part in my code where i use namespace) ... But i misunderstood, and i should use fully-qualified class name in the line with "$myclass = new MyClass()" (or use "use" instead)... These solutions need the auto loader function to be adjusted though, which i will do.. Anyway, thank you very much for your comment! I changed the namespace back (without the class name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read through the manual pages on [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and [namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) to make sure you understand the key concepts.

You have declared a class called `MyClass` inside the namespace `App\Classes`; that means that its *fully qualified* name is `App\Classes\MyClass` - that's the name you need to call it by from outside that namespace. There could simultaneously be a *different* class whose fully-qualified name was just `MyClass`, because it wasn't in any namespace, and any number of others in other namespaces, like `App\Security\MyClass`, `App\UI\MyClass`, etc.

Then you've attempted to reference a class in index.php called `MyClass`, which triggers the autoloader. The autoloader translates it to a path like `.../classes/MyClass.php`, and loads the right *file*; but that file defines *your namespaced class*. So after the autoloader has finished, *there is no class called `MyClass`, only `App\Classes\MyClass`* and the code fails.

If instead you write `new App\Classes\MyClass`, you'll get the *opposite* problem: the string passed to your autoloader is `'App\Classes\MyClass'` and you translate that to a file path like `'.../classes/App/Classes/MyClass.php'` - but *that's not where your file is*. (Adding `use App\ClassesMyClass` does the same thing - `use` statements are just compiler assistance to avoid writing out the fully-qualified name as often.)

What you need to do is *both*:

- Consistently use fully-qualified class names (or alias them with `use`)
- Lay out your files to match your namespace structure, so that your autoloader can find them, which generally means a directory per namespace

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!  I have two questions:
...1) Am I not using fully-qualified class names? (i thought i was doing it as described in psr-4, but i was unable to use the "use" command in index.php, probably for the reason you mentioned)

...2) Is it not possible to use the root of the server while still having a top-level namespace name? ("App" in this case)

Comment: @1337noobie 1) This line of code in your question is not using a fully-qualified name: `$myclass = new MyClass();` It either needs to be `$myclass = new App\Classes\MyClass();` or have `use App\Classes\MyClass;` at the top of the file. 2) You can lay your files out however you want, you just write whatever logic necessary in your autoloader function to translate name to location; but the whole point of namespaces is that you can have two classes both called `MyClass`, so putting all your classes in one flat directory isn't going to work.

Comment: I fixed the namespace, changed it from "App\Classes" to "App\Classes\MyClass", but the same problem still occurs... The second suggestion you made was to match the namespace structure, but if i do that, then i would have to move my files into a directory called "App", is that correct? Would that imply that the root directory of the server could not be used then?

Comment: @1337noobie I just answered that part: lay them out in whatever directories you like, but if you've got two classes called `App\UI\Control`  and `App\Permission\Control`, they can't both be files called 'Control.php' in the same directory. You could call them 'App__UI__Control.php' and 'App__Permission__Control.php' if you wanted, but more common is just to use a directory for each namespace.

Comment: @1337noobie 1) Understand that if you call your class `App\Classes\MyClass`, which you did by using a namespace, then you also need to call it by that name with `new App\Classes\MyClass`. 2) When you do `new App\Classes\MyClass` and your autoloader receives the string `"App\Classes\MyClass"`, then you need to write your autoloader in a way and lay out your files in a way that the correct file can be loaded from the name `"App\Classes\MyClass"`.

Comment: Also, you say "my second suggestion", but I explicitly said in the answer that you need to fix *both* things.

Comment: @IMPSoP Thank you for your response again!  So the only solution would be to change my autoloader function, to manually remove any "App" part and replace the "Classes" (upper case, in the namespace) with "classes" (lower case, the directory name), so that it would properly match my directory structure? ... I will read your comments again, i feel stupid if i misunderstood what you wrote before...

Comment: @1337noobie "Classes" is a pretty pointless namespace name. If you're going to put *everything* into that namespace, why bother with namespaces at all?

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback very much! You did not explicitly say this, but i guess i will have to change the autoloader function in the way i mentioned above (by manually removing "App" from the path, etc), so that i can use "new App\Classes\MyClass()" without that causing problems. @IMSoP I am still learning, so i hope i did not annoy you too much with my slowness in understanding... Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @1337noobie The point of namespaces is to *structure* your code, in a way that makes sense to you. It is *common* to lay out the directories the same way, because people generally find it *helpful* to have related classes in the same directory.

Comment: @IMSoP I agree, that seems useful indeed... So far, i only wanted to test if i could make the autoloader work, so i do not have any subdirectories in my classes directory (and namespace) for more distinct purposes... Honestly, i did not even think that far ahead, i just wanted to fix the errors first... I just feel disappointed that i can not use both the root of my server and a top-level namespace name at the same time, with the common autoloader function i was using...

Comment: @1337noobie I think it's possibly a case of trying to go *too* slowly: by trying to use namespaces "a little bit", you've actually ended up trying to do something *more complicated*, because it doesn't match any of the examples you're looking at. If instead of `App\Classes`, you make your first namespace `App\NotYetCategorised`, it will be much clearer how it relates to the examples you find in other people's code.

Comment: It took a while, but i managed to solve it! :) I added my solution in the post... Thank you for your time and your advice! @IMSoP